# I Want To Create A Collection Of Customers In Fire store And I want Invoices to be Associated with that collection in firebase

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Customers: [
{
Name:"helloWorld",
Phone:123,
Address:"address1",
Invoices:[{
product1:"sa",
price:"4500",
totalAmount:123,
},
{
product1:"Bca",
price:"2600",
totalAmount:2500,
}
]

```
},
```

{
Name:"NewCus",
Phone:788888888,
Address:"address2",
Invoices:[{
product1:"ase2",
price:"6500",
totalAmount:9000,
},
{
product1:"Bca",
price:"bha",
totalAmount:2500,
}
]

```
}
```

],

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways to do this. One option is to start with a users collection

```
users
   uid_0 //john's uid from their auth object
      name: "John"
   uid_1
      name: "Paul"
```

and then invoices are stores in an Invoices collection with a reference to the users uid

```
invoices
  invoice_0
     amount: "$100"
     user: "uid_0"
  invoice_1
     amount: "$50"
     user: "uid_0"
  invoice_2
     amount: "$22"
     user: "uid_1"
```

From the above, user John has two invoices; $100 and  $50, and uid_1 has one in invoice for $22

Depending on the queries you want to run you could also store a list of a users invoices within the users document as well.

```
users
   uid_0 //john's uid from their auth object
      name: "John"
      invoices:
         invoice_0: true //true is a placeholder value
         invoice_1: true
```